# javascript call function from variable not working

Tags: jquery, function, callback

my problem is

i have this code

`<a href="json.php?id=1" class="load_content" data-callback="load_content_func" > Load Content </a>`

and here's my jquery code

```
 // default load content function
 function load_content_func(){
    alert( 1 ) ;
 }
 $('a.load_content').click(function(){
     var h = $(this).attr('href');
     var func = {} ;
     var c = $(this).attr('data-callback');
     if(c){
        if(!$.isFunction(c)){
          func.ca ='load_content_func';
        }else{
          func.ca = c ;
        }
     }else{
        func.ca ='load_content_func';
     }
     var o = $(this) ;
     alert( func.ca ) ;
     func.ca ( o ) ;
     // func[ca]( o ) ;
 }) ;
```

this code return Error: TypeError: func.ca is not a function

my code func.ca refer to load_content_func  but not working here

how can i solve this

regards

Comment: it return in firefox console : Error: ReferenceError: ca is not defined

Comment: var func = {} ; // array

Comment: Try with `window[func.ca]()` See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4xKU2/2/

Comment: the same error with me 
Error: ReferenceError: ca is not defined
i will check it in jsfiddle may help

Comment: thank you @Satpal it worked very good :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
window[func.ca](o)
```

if the function is defined as root variable, or:

```
eval(func.ca + '(o)');
```

Any case I prefer something like:

```
var my_functions = {};

my_functions.load_content_func = function(){
    alert( 1 ) ;
 }
```

So you can call:

```
my_functions[func.ca](o);
```